# Should initialized final fields that are immutable always be made static?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there would ever be a legitimate use case for non-blank/initialized immutable final fields.

In other words:

```
class Foo {
  private final String bar = "bar";
}
```

Versus

```
class Foo {
  private static final String BAR = "bar";
}
```

Comment: private final String bar = “bar”;  simply have no sense, You just have a peer object constant variable, instead of single constant for the whole program. I.e. 'static final' reduces memory usage

Comment: @BoristheSpider It saves no space for the string, but it saves space for the reference.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `static final` field takes less memory than `instance final`. There is only one reference to the object, instead of one per instance.

Comment: @Boris the Spider Depending on JVM. JVM may or may not use string caching. HotSpot using it, so only one chaster array will be used (but I have no idea how much java.lang.String references). Another thing - javac compiler optimizations, which can add `static` automatically.  In case of message format (or StringBuilder for example), not thread safe means - don't used it nether as `static final` nor simply 'private final'. BTW. Joshua Bloch Effective Java explain all those things.

Comment: @VictorGubin using not threadsafe things as `final` fields is absolutely fine if you can guarantee that a single thread accesses the instance - for example in the case of an Actor System. As to your discussion about JVMs and caching etc as well as javac optimisations, this is somewhat confused.

Comment: @VictorGubin Sharing of String literals is required by the JLS. It is not a matter for JVM implementors to decide for themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer, as in most cases is: **it depends**.

What does it mean to make it `static`? Effectively it means to let all instances use *same value* of that field.

Most of the time immutable object could be shared among all instances without problems. Like in this case *it makes sense* to make it static since you want all instances of your class to use same *value* of that field.

But lets not forget that even if object is immutable it still has mutable property like [`monitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) which is used in synchronization mechanisms. Lets say your class have

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

and each instance is supposed to use its own `lock` object for synchronization (like `synchronize(lock){...}`). Despite the fact that `Object` is immutable, making `lock` static is not what we want (value of `lock` should not be shared, but *separate* for each instance).